# No resize dropdown list/select box arrow

Tags: css

On my website I've got a contact form with a dropdown list/select box. The box has a font-size of 14px. But only in Firefox the arrow of the dropdown list/select box (on the right) is resized according to the font-size. Is it possible to dissable this?

So the heigher you set the font-size, the larger the arrow in Firefox will be.

It has to be some kind of CSS style, because I've used 2 different scripts, and it's only occuring by 1 script.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Its been a historical bug that they just dont fix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @texasbruce is right, you can get around the awful looking scaled arrow by disabling the native style Firefox applies to menuList.

```
select {
-moz-appearance: none;
}
```

It's not pretty, but the button image should scale and not look too horrible. This SHOULD get rid of all styling but unfortunately it doesn't.

If you don't like that, you can try using

```
select {
-moz-appearance: button;
}
```

This gets rids of the arrow completely but it looks like a button, not like a drop-down.

Your best bet is to style it completely yourself. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)